# Regular expression testing for UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf

Today I decided to test a small function that checks if a string is UTF-8.

I used recommendations of the [Multilingual form encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php) and created a small helper:

```
function is_utf8($string) {
    if (strlen($string) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return preg_match('%^(?:
        [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]              # ASCII
        | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
        |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
        | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
        |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
        |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
        | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
        |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
    )*$%xs', $string);
}
```

As a test, I used a string with 196 characters. And just checked my helper. But browser doesn't display page with result, instead - 404 Page not found.

```
$string = "1234567890123456789012345678..."; // 196 characters here
echo strlen($string); // result - 196
var_dump(is_utf8($string)); // Error - Page not found!
```

But if I use 195 characters, everything works fine.

I've tried any of the characters, even spaces. This function only works with a string of no more than 195 characters.

Why?

Comment: You define it as `public static function is_utf8` whereas call it as `is_utf8($string)`. Either define a proper function http://us1.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php or a class and invoke it correspondingly

Comment: PS: removed `magic` tag - it probably should be replaced with `lack of basic syntax knowledge` one

Comment: @zerkms I use this method within a class as `self::is_utf8($string)`

Comment: What do we need to reproduce it? http://ideone.com/LwQzdi

Comment: `return $string === '' || preg_match('/^./su', $string) === 1;`

Comment: Have a look into your webservers `error.log` next. "Page not found" seems only a superficial message. If some regex limit is at fault (however unlikely), try atomic grouping `(?>` in place of `(?:`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks! Your example is really simple and it works perfectly! But I want to ask you, does it universal?

Comment: It should be universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as well, with a simple  regular expression and serialize

```
function check_utf8($str) {
     return (bool)preg_match('//u', serialize($str));
}
```

Comment: Hm, why do you need to serialize the string?

Comment: Probably. But why browser responds "Page not fount" if `$str` > 195 chars?

Comment: @Sergey Yakovlev: there is no general reason for that. Your script or webserver or hosting provider do that. There is nothing special with 195 chars string, and even with 196 chars long.

Answer (score 1):

Did a simple test.
I performed the function of 1000000 times. Looked who  faster.
I would also like to thank @mario for the help of an atomic grouping.

```
$string = "ывлдоkfdsuLIU(*knj4k58u7MJHKkiyhsf9hfhlknhlkjldfivjo8iulkjlgs".
          "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012".
          "ыдваолт ДЛЯОЧДльы0щ39478509г0*()*?Щчялртодылматцю4к 2ылвсголо".
          "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234".
          "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234".
          "asdfsd ds.kjasldasjlKUJLjLKZjulizL kzjxLkUJOLIULKM.LKl;.mcvss";

$s = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++)
{
        // algorithm
}

$e = microtime(true);

echo $e-$s;
```

And here result:

```
preg_match('//u', $string )
```

Result: **11.634791135788** sec

```
(preg_match('%^(?>
                [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]              # ASCII
                | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
                |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
                | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
                |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
                |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
                | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
                |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
            )*$%xs', $string)
```

Result: **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

```
preg_match('/^./su', $string)
```

Result: **12.27244400978** sec

```
mb_detect_encoding($string, array('UTF-8'), true)
```

Result: **15.370143890381** sec

And I also tried method proposed here by @helloworld

```
preg_match('//u', serialize($string))
```

Result: **23.193331956863** sec

Thank you all for your advice!
You helped me to understand

Answer (score 1):

If the String is too long -> PCRE crash

look http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1526 for solving